# Need to set portrait only for mobile devices

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, screen-orientation

I try using the following code.

```
        if (screenLayoutSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL || screenLayoutSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {
            requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
        }
```

code is woking fine. build successfully.

But there is an error on `requestedOrientation` and it says **"You should not lock orientation of your activities, so that you can support good user experience for any device or orientation."**

[Plese check this image for clear idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdShk.png)

how can I figure it out or is it ok to keep as it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a warning. As of now it is OK to keep it. Maybe they will force to change this in some later versions of studio. It is recommended not to lock the orientation for a good user experience.

Comment: alternatively, you may add @suppresslint as suggested by the tooltip to silence the annotation if you have any CI checking this kind of things.

Comment: It's detected as an error. Anyway, what is the best way to fix this?

Comment: The best way to fix it is to provide landscape version and don't lock the orientation. Now with this error the build will be successful and no problems will occur. But it reminds us to start handling the landscape versions and in some point of time they may make it compulsory.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Antonio said it's just a warning and you can ignore it for now.

Just add `@SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")` on the function where you are using Orientation code. i.e. -

```
@SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    if (screenLayoutSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL || screenLayoutSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {
            requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
    }
}
```

You can also achieve this without this Java code by using `screenOrientation` attribute in Manifest -

```
<activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />
```